# Samba Bonjour Python Script

Tags: python, ios, xcode6, samba, bonjour

I am trying to achieve a data transfer between samba (python script) and iPad.

However, when the python script crashes and i restart the script and try to connect from the iPad. I couldn't connect to the python script. iPad is searching for the connection.

When i say connection, i meant this:

> iPad will send "HI" to python samba, python samba will sent "YO" back if it receives "HI". Which i can't seem to achieve when the python script crashes.

Example:

> 1 possible crash will be when i close the app when the data is still transferring. I restart the python script and i couldn't get the iPad to connect.

I am still new to python and samba/bonjour. Can anyone guide me or enlighten on my problems?

Thanks!